# Power Pivot - Timeline linked to native Calendar Table can't be inserted anymore

Tags: calendar, powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot, timeline

I'm building a model in power pivot, and have so far 2 tables retrieved from API calls. I added a calendar, linked it to my tables, and it was working fine. I was able to add a timeline linked to my Calendar date field (not fact tables date fields).
[Link to the Calendar table are seen by Power Pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQFFI.png)

Then I updated the range of dates of my Calendar table, to go further in the past, and further in the future. Since then, when I try to add a timeline linked to the Calendar date field, nothing happens. It's weird, because Power Pivot is seeing the relationship with the calendar table, when I add the Calendar date fields in the power charts (see image 1). It's really the timeline that's not appearing anymore. If I try to add original date fields from fact tables, then the timeline adds correctly but that's not what I want.
[Steps to update Calendar date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaHSM.png)

[Clicking Okay does nothing, when it usually adds a timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQb62.png)

I don't know if it's a bug in Power Pivot or I broke something?

The Excel model is below

[Data model, with relationships to Calendar table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAm2T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the solution to my problem after 3 days of research. Basically by adding the timeline outside of a pivot chart, linking it to my calendar table, instead of not showing anything, it showed the error message pretty much saying that dates were not supported in Excel. So then I figured my date format was correct as it's the native calendar table, so it was probably a problem linked to the range. After a few tests, it seems anything before 1900 is not supported in the timeline, same goes for after 2099. Adjusting the range fixed it!